# Running PIL in Python with Canopy

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, canopy

I am trying to run a program with PIL Enthought Canopy version 1.5.1(64 bit) but I am getting an error saying "DLL load failed: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail." Can someone give me some suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) This is a year-old version of Canopy. As described in the following article, we suggest a ***complete*** uninstall and reset, followed by re-installing the current version:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/54134224-Repeated-errors-starting-or-updating-the-Canopy-GUI-application

2) PIL has been completely replaced by Pillow (which emulates PIL, so no need to modify your code). After you have done a clean install of Canopy 1.5.5, update Pillow in the Canopy package manager.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to reinstall the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 redistributable package: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092